# Where is log directory defined in relative path placed in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I have a MVC web Spring application and logging I do with Log4j. I need to know where my logs are created and where log files are placed. I went throught all Tomcat installation directory but it seems that the log directory doesn't exist there (or I haven't found it...).

I have such FileAppender specification:

```
log.dir=logs/
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${log.dir}/application.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.conversionPattern}
```

It works for me when I have standalone application. But I cannot find directory with my logs, where can Tomcat place this directory? Should I define log director location with full path instead of relative path? I would avoid to specify full path to no to be limited by full path specification.

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: If the path is relative, i.e. `logs/` then the path is relative to `CATALINA_BASE` - whatever that is set to in your installation. For example on Ubuntu the installation dir is `CATALINA_HOME` which is `/usr/share/tomcat7` and `CATALINA_BASE` is `/var/lib/tomcat7` and the logs directory is a simlink to `/var/log/tomcat7` by default.

Comment: @RossDrew - I use OS X (10.9 - Mavericks)

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Now I checked it and I have not set CATALINA_BASE system variable. Should I point it to my Tomcat installation directory?

Comment: If you attach `jconcole` to your tomcat instance then you can see when these are set to, they are system variables passed in by the startup script. If the installation works as is then changing the path may well break it...